# Short story about dinosaurs being the companions of humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this in a compendium; probably originally from a magazine.  It was set in the remote past.  Dinosaurs (tame) were the companions of humans.  These humans were scientifically advanced but had no compassion at all.  A woman is wounded and is ignored as she lies dying on the ground.

There is a great quote from the protagonist to the effect of "Is life nothing but eating, breeding, and the pursuit of scientific knowledge?"

Comment: Do you remember what year you read this? Or a rough decade/time period?

Comment: @MotherOrganoid - I am pretty sure this story was from "the golden age" - possibly 1930s?

Comment: Probably not Dinotopia then.